# How can I render template data without serializing the model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

this is how I am doing it currently but what I want to do is to render data from template without doing this (serialized_model.items[0]):

```
template: function(serialized_model){
        var user_data_tmpl = $("#user-data-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(user_data_tmpl);
        return template(serialized_model.items[0]);
    }
```

I get the results fine from a hard time but this is the full code:

The Model & Collection:

```
window.UserData = {};

UserData.Model = Backbone.Model.extend();

UserData.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model:UserData.Model,

    url: '/getUserData',

    parse: function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

});
```

The View:

```
UserData.View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

   template: function(serialized_model){

        var user_data_tmpl = $("#user-data-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(user_data_tmpl);
        return template(serialized_model.items[0]);
    }

});
```

The template:

```
<script id='user-data-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    <a href="#" id="logout"> Logout </a>
    uid:{{uid}} username:{{username}} clave:{{clave}}
</script>
```

The JSON:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"logged":true,"uid":14,"clave":14,"depto":9,"nivel":5},"report":null}
```

Comment: "what I want to do is to render data from template without doing this" ... without doing what?  Using templates?  Using models to power those templates?  Extracting the data from the model?  I'm not sure what your question is ... if you're going to use templates, and you want to fill in the values in those templates with data from your models, then at some point you have to get the model's data out of it (eg. via `toJSON`), as Handlebars doesn't take raw Backbone Models.

Comment: @machineghost Sorry I edited the content, what I want to achieve is to compile the data from the template automatically without doing all the stuff inside the template funcion, previously I used to do that in a single line: template: Handlebars.compile($('#user-data-template').html()),

Comment: I understand now (I think); please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we've handled this in our codebase is simply to have a `BaseView` class that all of our views extend from.  This view has a `renderTemplate` method and some supporting methods, which look something like this:

```
renderTemplate: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.templatedHtml());
    return this;
},
templatedHtml: function() {
    return this.template(this.getTemplateData());
},
getTemplateData: function() {
    return _({}).extend(this.model.toJSON());
}
```

Our's is a little more complex than that, but hopefully you get the idea.  The point is, if you build yourself a `renderTemplate` method on a `BaseView` class, then you can make new Views ...

```
var YourView = BaseView.extend({
    template: yourCompiledTemplate
});

var yourViewInstance = new YourView({model: someModel});
// Apply template to yourViewInstance:
yourViewInstance.renderTemplate();
```

That way:

- everything happens automatically
- you don't have to repeat anything
- if you want to add more (eg. you want to be able to define templates as strings, or you want to define them in script tags and specify the ID of those tags instead, and have your view compile that in to a Handlebars templates for you) it's super-easy to add